# Should the MyFamily option be set for bridges?

Tags: relays, bridge, myfamily

I am running two relays and a couple of bridges. Currently only the relays have the MyFamily option set. Should the bridges also have it set? Should they include the relays or should they not? Is this option even used on bridges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, absolutely not. The setting will be [ignored](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/4657) anyways. The default `torrc` file also [has a comment](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/5511)) which explains this setting.

You don't want your bridge address listed anywhere publically where it can be discovered (eg. in another relay's "My family" line).

From ticket #[5511](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/5511)):

> as rransom pointed out to me, bridges should NEVER see their fingerprints set in the MyFamily setting.
>
> rransom | DO NOT include a bridge's fingerprint in any Tor instance's
>   MyFamily torrc line.
>
> rransom | Anyone can use a bridge's fingerprint
>   to find its current TCP address.